# Js files in common jsp not working when include common jsp in other jsp page with js in same page

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jsp

> common.jsp

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="slim-footer">
    <div class="container">
        <p> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria- 
hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria- 
hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin-square" aria- 
hidden="true"></i></a> <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square" aria- 
hidden="true"></i></a> 
        </p>

    </div>
    <!-- container -->
</div>


<script src="<c:url value="/resources/design/lib/jquery/js/jquery.js"/>"> 
</script>

<script src="<c:url 
value="/resources/design/lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"/>"></script>

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/design/js/angular.min.js"/>"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/design/utilJs/headerfunction.js"/>"> 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

> temp.jsp

```
</div>

<%@include file='common.jsp'%>
</body>

<script src="<c:url value="/resources/design/temp.js"/>"></script>
```

> Description

```
  Now, I'm working in web project where headerFunction.js in common.jsp page
```

not working  when including the common.jsp page in temp.jsp page . But the temp.js in that page working .Kindly share some idea to make both js work .Thanks in advance

Comment: Not terribly familiar with jsp here, but would the above code not result in a second html tag inside the body? From an html standpoint that is invalid and that maybe that causes the browsers to ignore your script tags.

Comment: Please explain your problem more clearly. There are formatting errors in your question as well

Comment: Hi, this is the problem .I have two Jsp Pages ,they are common.jsp &  temp.jsp . In common jsp ,I have scripts which will be used as common scripts in all pages . In temp.jsp , I include the common.jsp page &  some other scripts . Once the program executed , the scripts in the temp.jsp page only worked ,but the scripts in included page not worked. I need make both scripts work at one execution.@Fabulous